# How can I make same (WPF) UI screen apperance on both Laptop and 22" inch Monitor? please help me here

Tags: wpf

We are doing UI screens for WPF application on Laptop But we are planing to give demo on 22"inch Monitor. Here Dimensions are getting changed when we see UI screens on 22"inch Monitor. How can I make same UI screen apperance on both Laptop and 22" inch Monitor? please help me here....

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the resolution of her laptop screen?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an absolute layout, where specific X/Y/Height/Width is being defined for every control? If you use other types of layouts, they are more relative to window height/width and automatically handle these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, We are mention the X/Y/Height/Width for each control on the WPF window.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire application in the [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) control. As long as you don't have rasterized images, nothing will look stretched.

Comment: By my comment, they are forcing the height and width of each control. So by definition, there is no stretching. So he likely wants the layout to adjust to resizing of the screen.